# In a node js http server how to know when an http exchange ended?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an http server application in node js. I want to have an event that triggers when an http exchange is over but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to do it the way it would be done with other streams in node js using `.on('end', callback)` but it doesn't seem to work:

what I tried (which doesn't work):

```js
const Http = require('http');

const httpServer = Http.createServer((httpRequest, httpResponse) => {
    console.log('<started>');
    httpResponse.on('end', () => console.log('<ended>'));
    httpResponse.end('END');
    console.log('<finished>');
});
httpServer.listen(80);
```

what I expect my console to print after navigating to `localhost` in my browser:

```
<started>
<finished>
<ended>
```

what I really get:

```
<started>
<finished>
```

How to do this correctly? I want a callback that triggers when the server finished streaming the response stream for this http request to the client.

Comment: http exchange over event you can check in your specific route, where the request has been sent to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpResponse` is a [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage), you can listen to `close` event (instead of `end`), the event will be emitted when the request has been completed.

```js
const Http = require('http');

const httpServer = Http.createServer((httpRequest, httpResponse) => {
  console.log('<started>');
  httpResponse.on('close', () => console.log('<ended>'));
  httpResponse.end('END');
  console.log('<finished>');
});
httpServer.listen(80);
```